# selecting distinct column name with respectives values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table as

```
P_Id | userid | year | month | day
-----+--------+------+-------+------
 3   |      3 | 2011 |     2 |    2
 5   |      1 | 2011 |     2 |    3
16   |      8 | 2011 |     3 |    4
 5   |      3 | 2011 |     4 |    4
17   |     1  | 2011 |     4 |    6
 8   |      4 | 2011 |     7 |    7
 9   |      3 | 2011 |     8 |    8
10   |      8 | 2011 |     9 |    9
```

I want to select distinct column i.e userid but also the respective value of year month and year which were encountered first.

For given above  table following should be output

```
P_Id | userid | year | month | day
-----+--------+------+-------+------
   3 |      3 | 2011 |     2 |    2
   5 |      1 | 2011 |     2 |    3
  16 |      8 | 2011 |     3 |    4
   8 |      4 | 2011 |     7 |    7
```

or
If i am ordering the table by year,month and day 
userid which is encountered first must only be selected and rest must be not be selected

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: i am trying but not able to get respective values of userid

Comment: @Sunny : If you think one of below answer is right, then PLEASE accept it... This is how SO works...

Comment: i am not getting desired result

Comment: Surely you don't want a row that says `5 |      1 | 2011 |     4 |    3` or `17 | 1 | 2011 | 2 | 3` which could be made by taking the value of different rows for different columns.

Comment: let us take userid 3 it has  three rows i want to select one of these three rows having minimum value of year,month,day.In this case       3 | 2011 |     2 |    2    should be selected. if we use minimum function for year,month and day i will not get desired row. Similarly i want this to done for all userids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put year, month and day to native **date** column and do this:

```
select p_id, userid, min(the_date) from table group by p_id, userid
```

It will provide the fastest result.

If you cant modify your table and should use year+month+day then you can convert this values to date and still use **min** function.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this wouldn't give him a row like `17 | 1 | 2011 | 2 | 3`.

Comment: @Ken is right. This will not show what is described in the question. It will show multiple rows per userid.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ta.*
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT userid
      FROM tableX
    ) AS di
  JOIN
    tableX AS ta
      ON ta.P_id = 
         ( SELECT ti.P_id
           FROM tableX AS ti
           WHERE ti.userid = di.userid
           ORDER BY ti.year, ti.month, ti.day
           LIMIT 1
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is as follows;

```
select * from (select min(p_id)p_id,userid, min(year)year,min(month)month,min(day)day from tsil group by userid) t order by p_id;
```

and here is the test;

```
create table tsil(p_id int, userid int, year int, month int, day int);
insert into tsil values (3,3,2011,2,2)
                                ,(5,1,2011,2,3)
                                ,(16,8,2011,3,4)
                                ,(5,3,2011,4,4)
                                ,(17,1,2011,4,6)
                                ,(8,4,2011,7,7)
                                ,(9,3,2011,8,8)
                                ,(10,8,2011,9,9);
commit;
select * from (select max(p_id)p_id,userid, min(year)year,min(month)month,min(day)day from tsil group by userid) t order by p_id;
drop table tsil;
```

and here is the result; what you expected.

```
+------+--------+------+-------+------+
| p_id | userid | year | month | day  |
+------+--------+------+-------+------+
|    3 |      3 | 2011 |     2 |    2 |
|    5 |      1 | 2011 |     2 |    3 |
|    8 |      4 | 2011 |     7 |    7 |
|   16 |      8 | 2011 |     3 |    4 |
+------+--------+------+-------+------+
```

Comment: by using min function i am getting wrong columns which i want

Comment: this query will not work. The main problem be with dates like (2011, 2, 10) and (2010, 4, 10) for same user id. Your query will return non-existent date (2010, 2, 10)